# VBA send mail with gmail

Tags: vba, excel, email

I want to copy a range (a1:k38) from a worksheet to a new workbook then the new workbook has  to be send by gmail.
The mail sending works, but the Attachment cannot be openend, says its corrupt, also if i attach another .xls file. Also i cannot get the code working to copy a range with picture to a newworkbook.

What i have so far

```
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "Copy of " & wb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb.Name, Len(wb.Name) - InStrRev(wb.Name, ".", , 1)))

wb.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "someone@gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "*******"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
    .Update
End With



With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = "me@hotmail.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .From = """Dave"" <me@hotmail.com>"
    .Subject = "New form"
    .AddAttachment TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
    .Send
End With

Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
```

Comment: Try adding a message in the body of email.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, that solved the issue with opening  the attachment